# Navigation Drawer + actionbar issues using sdk11

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, drawer

I am using a `Navigation Drawer` as shown in this repository

https://github.com/sgolivernet/curso-android-src/tree/develop/android-navigationdrawer . when i use it on a virtual device with `sdk-19` the code runs perfectly but on `sdk-11` there seems to be a problem because `onPrepareOptionsMenu` never get a call when I open the `Navigation Drawer`. Anyone has this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: why not use the navigation drawer that is build into the support library instead of using a 3rd party library that does not even seem to work correctly?

Comment: It's not a 3rd party library it's just a project using android libraries. I have done it by myself but i have the same problem.

Comment: ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.this);
Usually I use supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()